# cordova-plugin-nativeaudio no longer works in Android 7 (worked flawlessly in 6)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I have developed an app that is specifically for Android using Cordova and Framework7. It plays mp3's which are packaged with the app using **cordova-plugin-nativeaudio** (Found here [cordova-plugin-nativeaudio](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio)).

This has been working flawlessly in Android 6.0.1. However, my tablet updated to 7.0 and all the audio stopped working. It does not throw errors, but rather skips the playback of the audio and runs the success callback immediately.

I think i have narrowed down the issue to the new [file access permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) in Android 7 but I do not know how to fix it. The plugin doesn't seem to cater for this new **FileProvider** stuff.

I tried installing a plugin which utilizes this new permission structure but I cannot get it to work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting code will help people answer and understand your question better.

Comment: It isnt really a code thing as all the code works on Android 6, but rather a change in permissions structure that i dont know how to implement :/